# What is the relationship between TYPO3 cms and TYPO3 flow?

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x, typo3-flow

TYPO3 CMS is an Open Source content management system and TYPO3 Flow is a PHP-based application framework, then is there any relation between TYPO3 CMS and TYPO3 Flow. Please help me to find an answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Flow is a PHP framework from TYPO3 family, which can be used on its own. TYPO3 family has a few more members, the most important are TYPO3 CMS and Neos. See the  [TYPO3 family brand page](http://typo3.org/about/the-brand/the-typo3-family/).

Released at the end of 2011, Flow was initially developed as a foundation for a next generation web publishing platform called Neos (released one year later). Nowadays Flow is used as a standalone framework, suitable for building complex web applications, offering advanced features like Dependency Injection, Aspect Oriented Programming and more.

Flow - together with Fluid, the templating engine used by Flow - is backported to TYPO3 CMS as a `extbase` and `fluid` system extensions. It is just a backport, made to ease developing TYPO3 CMS extensions and offer some of sophisticated Flow features there. Though, you cannot just take Flow package and drop it into TYPO3 CMS, expecting it will work. Although under rapid development, TYPO3 CMS has its historical background and the core principals are different than in newer/younger Flow.

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct relation between TYPO3 CMS and TYPO3 Flow. Anyway the basic ideas and concepts of building web applications have been backported to TYPO3 CMS within the system extension "extbase". Many features of Flow are present in extbase as well, so that CMS extension developers can rely on a alike framework. A incomlete list is:

- MVC Design Pattern
- Domain Driven Design
- Dependency Injection
- Repository Pattern for access the database
- Folder Structure
- Signals and Slots
- Use of Template enginge "Fluid"

Since extbase is an backport of Flow it relies on the contribution of its maintainers to keep up with new features introduces to flow.

On a sidenote: in contrast to TYPO3 CMS, TYPO3 Neos is completly build on top of Flow (in fact Neos is a Flow package), so there is a direct relation.